# Which is higher enegy/outermost, $s$ or $d$ orbitals of transition metals?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

The outermost electron shell of Au is 6s but the highest energy orbitals electrons occupy is 5d. Likewise, the outermost shell of Co is 4s while the highest energy orbit is 3d.

Are these correct? I've heard that the malleability of Au stems from the isotropic s orbit, which is located outmost side. But I've also heard that magnetic anisotropy of Co is relevant to the anisotropic d orbit.

I'm confused. If 5d of Au is the highest, the most relevant electron orbit should be d. If 4s of Co is outmost, the most relevant orbit should be s. The outermost electron shell and the highest energy of the orbit are not equal?
Could anybody help my dull brain?

Answer (score 2):

The orbitals (or subshells) are distributions of charge (and of momentum of that charge), so they are not sharply defined in space. This means that the orbital which extends furthest from the nucleus might also be the same one which has the highest probability near the nucleus. So to say which one is "outermost" you might have to be a bit more specific. e.g. which one has the highest mean radius or mean square radius or something like that.

Now for energy. This comes in both kinetic and potential forms so it is a function of both position and velocity for electrons in an atom. For this reason an orbital with a high average potential energy (so "outermost" in that sense) does not necessarily have the highest total energy. The kinetic energy has to be allowed for as well.

The orbital with the highest energy is the one with the lowest ionization energy. This is usually also the one which can be called "outermost" by some position-based measure, such as mean radius, but it does not have to be.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be phenomenologically answered by using the Aufbau/Madelung rules, which state that orbitals are filled from lowest to highest energy in order of increasing $n+l$ quantum numbers, with ties broken by the lower lower value of $n$. For instance, if we just write out a table of possible quantum number values, we find,
\begin{gather}
\begin{array}{cccc} 
n & l & n+l & \text{label} \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1s \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 & 2s \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 2p \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 3s \\ 
3 & 1 & 4 & 3p \\
3 & 2 & 5 & 3d \\
4 & 0 & 4 & 4s \\
4 & 1 & 5 & 4p \\
4 & 2 & 6 & 4d \\
4 & 3 & 7 & 4f 
\end{array}
\end{gather}
and so forth. This gives an orbital filling order of $1s\rightarrow 2s\rightarrow 2p \rightarrow 3s \rightarrow 3p \rightarrow 4s \rightarrow 3d \rightarrow \cdots$. As you can see, the $3d$ orbital has a higher value of $n+l$ than the $4s$ orbital, so it is typically not filled first. This trend generally works, so far as we know, for the entire periodic table of the elements. The only exceptions are orbital filling oddities having to do with transition metals where half-filling the sub shells can result in lower energy due to electron-electron repulsion (e.g. chromium has valence configuration $4s^13d^5$).

A slightly easier way to summarize the way we fill orbitals is that you read the periodic table like a book from left to right and top to bottom, assigning each "box" an electron and filling in the blocks as shown on this periodic table. This will give you the proper electron configuration when you stop at the atom's position on the periodic table, with the modest exception of a few transition metals with preferred half-filling. This goes according to the following excellent image.
[image: Periodic table with electron filling rules embedded. Image taken from chemistry libre texts, contributed by Sarah Faizi]

As for your questions on anisotropy, I am genuinely not sure what you mean. In all cases, a single atom will have a spherical symmetry, and the wave function will extend over all of space with an exponentially decaying fall off. While it is true that some orbitals have much larger values of the expected value of the radius, there are also variable degrees to which outer electrons are screened by other electrons in multi-electron atoms. This results in quirks like the $4s$ orbital having lower energy than the $3d$ orbital, which can be somewhat hand-wavily justified by looking at the radial components of the wave functions for the hydrogen atom (though this comparison should be taken with a large grain of salt! This is not the same system as a multi-electron atom!),
[image: 3d and 4s orbitals and their radial wave functions and radial probability density functions. Images are from an original program I wrote in Python.]